Fisher exact test in correlated dataset
Suppose I have n subjects. I have measured them twice with some binary outcomes. Now I want to test whether outcomes measured earlier agree with outcome measured later. Usually, I would need to do this by McNemar's test instead of Chi square test/Fisher exact test, the latter of which does not account repeated measurements.
$Q:$ Suppose the data (n<50) was given and the identifiers were erased. One is forced to use either Chi square test or Fisher exact test. Assuming correlation is positive in this case. Is it OK to use Fisher exact test in this situation? Note that Fisher exact test conditions upon the margins, whereas Chi squares conditions upon independence assumption.
$Q':$ How bad is the coverage of Chi square and Fisher exact tests in this case with correlation>0.2?
